# Extracting data from SQLite and inserting to remote database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, sqlite

Ok, newish to computer science and somehow SO.

My lecturer said that if we could implement a remote database on our app then it would greatly improve our mark. We have 4 days and it is only me and two others..

From what i understand:

1. The data has to be extracted from the SQLlite database as either
   JSON or XML
2. The data has to be sent over HTTP to our remote server, so we
   need to connect our database with the remote server
3. The data has to be parsed before being inserted into the mySQL
   tables in the remote server.

Even though android uses XML I assume it makes no difference if JSON is used? Have parsed data and connected to server with PHP before, but am not as familiar with java.

Any pointer to resources or tutorials on the topic are much appreciated, we are trying to give this a proper go and realise we are going to run into millions of difficulties so want to make as much progress in as much time as possible. ANY information is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can find so many things in google, though, I will suggest you to do one thing at a time. Having that said, here are some pointers: http://www.sgoliver.net/ , http://www.vogella.com/android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that I may not understand your question fully, but I hope that the following reference may help you a bit.

This is a tutorial to SQLite database in Android: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

The following is a code snipet of what I had did before to connect to a PHP file on the server, and extract or insert data into the database on the server through this PHP file.

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost;
    httppost = new HttpPost(link_to_php_file); 
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //Where you can pass parameter to the php file
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", value));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", value2));
    String str="";
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        str = Utils.convertStreamToString(entity.getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in connection " + e.toString());
    }
    return str;

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
        JSONArray result_array = null;
        try {
            result_array = (JSONArray) new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }                           

        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                //Do something with the result...                           
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
};//End Of PostExecute
}.execute(); //End Of Async
```

Comment: I think that I didnt understand my question.

But yes I think this could be a help, and is what I'm looking for - the java code sends the json objects in an array  to a php file on the server, which parses the code and sends it to the database, acting as intermediary.